# "An illegal attempt was made to upload a document" when passing a url in a FormEncodedHTTPEntityCreator

Tags: knime

I am uploading a file with a post request. In the form data, being inspired by `curl` I have given the following `form` parameters `type=144&parent_id=819449945&name=success5&file=@D:\CustomTools\omicron\test.xlsx`

I then pass this to an HTTP Entity Creator hoping for my file to end up at the other end. Instead I get the following error:

```
An illegal attempt was made to upload a document
```

What does this error mean in the specific case of Knime, and how can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add the `&file=@D:\CustomTools\omicron\test.xlsx`, this syntax is not supported. Instead this is the part which is provided by the [Multipart Encoded HTTP Entity Creator](https://nodepit.com/node/ws.palladian.nodes.retrieval.utils.multipart.MultipartEncodedHttpEntityCreatorNodeFactory) node.

Comment: I am not sure I'm following correctly. So I will add a `file to binary object`, connect it to the `multipart encoded http entity` and then connect that one to a `table row` and then finally to the `http retriever`?

Comment: That's roughly how it should work. The structure above looks fine at first sight, except that it should be the other mentioned node (i.e. **not** Form Encoded). I think I answered another question from you recently where I posted an example workflow -- should should give the idea on how to make it work.